# Is this an elliptic integral or not?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, elliptic-integrals

I am working with the following differential equation:
$$4\left(\frac{dz}{dx}\right)^2+z^4=4$$
On rearrangement, this yields
$$\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{\sqrt{4-z^4}}{{2}}$$
Using $z=\sqrt{2}\tan \theta$, we further get
$$\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1-2\sin^2\theta}}=\frac{dx}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Now, as per [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170602/integral-of-root-of-sec-x), [this](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-evaluate-int-sqrt-sec-x-dx-If-yes-then-how-to-evaluate-it), [this](https://www.askiitians.com/forums/Integral-Calculus/what-is-the-integral-of-sqrt-sec-x-dx-plz-answe_167506.htm) and other links, the term on the left is an elliptic integral. But [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html) says that, for an elliptic integral of the form $\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\theta}}$, the bound on $k$ is given by $$0<k^2<1$$

But for my integral, $k^2=2>1$, which is also causing me difficulty in numerically trying to integrate the problem.

Can somebody tell me what is correct and what not and how I should proceed to integrate the LHS of the equation, numerically (or if possible analytically)?

Comment: Shouldn't $$\dfrac{dz}{dx}= ~\pm~\dfrac{\sqrt{4-z^4}}{{2}}?$$ Also, this is now a Separable Equation.

Comment: What do you do when the denominator is $\sqrt{-1}$?

Comment: @Moo Yes, it is a separable equation, but cannot be solved analytically. You can try. Boils down to that form mentioned above.

Comment: @Akababa Unable to comprehend what you meant to say.

Comment: $1-2\sin^2x$ can be negative.

Comment: @Akababa Yes, it can be. That's what I have said: "Which is also causing me difficulty in numerically trying to integrate the problem." Can you tell me what I need to do?

Comment: Idk, I got something a lot different. $\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{(3\cos^2\theta-1)(\cos^2\theta+1)}}=\frac{dx}2$. I think it's better without substituting $\theta$.

Comment: I suspect the substitution was in fact $z=\sqrt{2}\tan\theta$. Anyway, in which range of $z$ do you want to find a numerical solution?

Comment: @SangchulLee Oh, that was a typo. Corrected. Actually I want to find a solution for $0<x<50$, since $x$ is tne independant variable.

Answer (score 5):

$$\frac{dz}{dx}=\pm\frac{\sqrt{4-z^4} }{{2}}$$
$$dx=\pm 2\frac{dz}{\sqrt{4-z^4}}$$
$$x(z)=\pm 2\int\frac{dz}{\sqrt{4-z^4}}+c$$
This is an elliptic integral of first kind.

The inverse function $z(x)$ is a Jacobi elliptic function :
$$z(x)=\pm \sqrt{2}\text{ sn}\left(\frac{x-c}{\sqrt{2}} \: \Bigg| \: -1 \right)$$
sn$(u|m)$ is the Jacobi elliptic sine function, with $u=\frac{x-c}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $m=-1$.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_elliptic_functions).

Answer (score 3):

This equation is interesting in that the points $(z, z') = (\sqrt{2}, 0)$ and $(-\sqrt{2},0)$ are equilibria. So whenever $z$ hits $\pm\sqrt{2}$ the solution does not extend in a natural way. I guess that any physically meaningful solution will immediately escape this equilibria. One such solution is

$$ z(x) = \sqrt{2} \operatorname{dn} \left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \, \middle| \, 2\right), $$

which satisfies $z(0) = \sqrt{2}$ and $z'(0) = 0$. Here, $\operatorname{dn}(\cdot \mid m)$ is the [*Jacobi delta amplitude*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_elliptic_functions#Definition_as_inverses_of_elliptic_integrals) and we are adopting the convention that $m = k^2$ is the parameter and $k$ is the elliptic modulus. This at least provides a way of computing $z(x)$, but I am not sure if $\operatorname{dn}$ can be easily computed in a numerical way.

Finally, here are some computations using Mathematica.

[image: Graph of z(x)]

[image: Proofread]

Comment: A complete answer +1

Answer (score 3):

The solutions of 
$$a\left(\frac{dz}{dx}\right)^2+z^4=b$$ are given in terms of the Jacobi elliptic function 
$$z=\pm\sqrt[4]{b}\, \text{sn}\left(\left.\frac{\sqrt[4]{b} }{\sqrt{a}}x+c\right|-1\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

As a supplement to the fine answers already provided by Sangchul and *M.* Jacquelin:

The *elliptic functions* (not elliptic integrals!) that solve the nonlinear ODE presented in the OP satisfy what are called the *reciprocal modulus* and *imaginary modulus* identities, which are useful in the respective cases of $k>1$ and purely imaginary $k$.

(At this juncture, I would like to remind everybody to [mind their argument conventions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/108659); the state of affairs is already confusing as it is.)

For example, with *M'sieur* Jacquelin's solution, applying [this imaginary modulus identity](https://dlmf.nist.gov/22.17.E6) yields

$$\sqrt{2}\,\operatorname{sn}\left(\frac{x-c}{\sqrt{2}}\middle|-1\right)=\operatorname{sd}\left(x-c\middle|\frac12\right)$$

(or $\operatorname{sd}\left(x-c,\frac1{\sqrt 2}\right)$ if you prefer using moduli instead of parameters).

(A similar operation can be done for the answer of *M.* Leibovici.)

Sangchul's solution, OTOH, admits a [reciprocal modulus transformation](https://dlmf.nist.gov/22.17.E4):

$$\sqrt{2} \operatorname{dn} \left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \, \middle| \, 2\right)=\sqrt{2}\operatorname{cn}\left(x\middle| \frac12\right)$$

Of interest is that all the transformed answers now have $m=\frac12$, which is now more amenable to AGM-type computations unlike the forms with parameters outside $[0,1)$.